# Android cannot set column number for HORIZONTAL recycler view grid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have a `recyclerview` as `grid view` and its horizontal like this

```
 recyclerView_Day = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.day_recycler);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3);
        gridLayoutManager.setSpanCount(3);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new
                GridLayoutManager(context, 1,gridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView_Day.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView_Day.setAdapter(new DyaAdapter(context))
```

but its not working , so i need to set a 3 column in recyclerview !

Comment: What is the output you get? and what you expect instead? can you give more details?

Comment: Show the DyaAdapter code and the item xml!

I think you set the item width to match_parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a **GridView** instead of recyclerview, and set columnCount to 3 in gridview, this will easily do your work.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which you can achieve this with RecyclerView
1. Use GridLayoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
  adapter = new DyaAdapter(context);
  recyclerView_Day.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2. Another way is to user LinearLayoutManager with orientation as Vertical.

Here you can set an item custom data and inflate a view with 3 same views.

Layout file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/v1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/v2"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/v3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i need it horizontal and grid

Comment: Grid with 3 columns?